# Как вернуть вектор из класса?

Tags: c++, классы, vector, struct

У меня есть класс. Допустим, пусть это будет класс, представляющий собой координатную сетку. Координаты в ней хранятся в векторе, где каждая точка - это структура с полями x и y. Я хочу реализовать метод, позволяющий получить коллекцию всех точек на сетке. Для этого мне надо, чтобы метод класса возвращал вектор с точками (или может есть более удобный способ?). Однако возникла проблема (в с++ я новичек): как мне его вернуть? Сам метод я реализовал. Однако как мне присвоить возвращаемое значение переменной? Переменная должна при инициализации быть такого же типа, как и значение, возвращаемое из функции. И тут проблема:

Из функции возвращается вектор, содержащий структуры Point. Структура Point объявлена внутри класса. То есть в самом коде я не могу написать

> vector  vec = grid.get_all_points();

Что делать? Вынести структуру Point в область видимости всего кода? А если я хочу сохранить объявление этой структуры внутри класса?

Код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class RSGrid {

private:

    struct Point {
        float x, y;
    };

    vector <Point> points;

public:

    void add_point(float x, float y) {

        Point p = { x, y };
        this->points.push_back(p);

    }

    vector <Point> get_all_points() {

        return this->points;

    }

};

int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

    RSGrid grid = RSGrid();
    grid.add_point(1, 1);
    grid.add_point(12, 1);
    grid.add_point(1, 2);

    vector <Point>

    system("pause"); return 0;

}
```

Comment: Непонятно, что тут мешает объявить эту структуру в глобальной области видимости или с модификатором `public`, если она и так используется при возврате из публичной функции. А в коде обычно нет никакой необходимости копировать объявление возвращаемого значения, достаточно использовать вывод типа: `auto & points{grid.get_all_points()};` ЗЫ в геттере желательно возвращать ссылку, а не копировать каждый раз новый вектор.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что делает этот код в вашем комментарии? Буду рад, если подскажете auto & points{grid.get_all_points()};

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логично, если класс объявлен внутри приватной части, то он не будет доступен вне кода класса. Но можно просто перенести его в публичную часть класса

```
class RSGrid {

public:
    struct Point {
        float x, y;
    };
    
private:

    vector <Point> points;

public:
```

и теперь можно писать вот так

```
vector <RSGrid::Point> v = grid.get_all_points();
```

Но что делать, если расскрывать тип внутри не очень хочется и нужно его оставить в приватной части? Тоже можно. В публичную часть класса дописываем такое

```
public:
  using Points = std::vector<Point>;
```

и функцию теперь можно вот так объявить

```
Points get_all_points() {
  return this->points;
}
```

и вот так использовать

```
RSGrid::Points v = grid.get_all_points();
```

P.S. В приведенном коде возвращается копия внутреннего вектора. Возможно так и нужно. А может есть смысл возвратить его по ссылке. Но это уже Вам виднее.